# does gradle uses a cacerts file other than the javavm's?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am now behind a firewall that resigns every page with a different certificate. Work related. So every https access is now signed with a self(workplace)-signed-certificate.

As a result, a lot of software is broken.

Android studio lets you store certificates and use those, but gradle still complains.

Short of adding the certificate to the running javavm cacerts with keytool, is there a more gradle-specific solution? (it looks like gradle does not use android-studio's cacerts file)

I had no luck searching for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle uses the cacerts file from the JVM, with which it was started (this may be another JVM than Android Studio uses, especially if Android Studio uses a packaged one). So just check the log output from the Gradle build, you should see at the beginning, which JVM it is using.

Comment: I take it there is no specific way for gradle to handle http certificates. I was hoping there was so as to know what other java applications were hit by this change. Thank you